Why does my Django URL parameter result in an error?
I am a Django noob and this is my first post in stackoverflow. I need help in fixing my code. It was working well previously until I got an error regarding URL parameters as I tried adding an image for each person object using a foreign key. I'd like to improve with the help of your feedback. Please let me know if you have an idea of what changes I can do to make this project work.
This is my code from the different django files:
models.py
class Person(models.Model):
    person_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.person_text


class PersonDetail(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    person_subtext = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.person_subtext[:50]}..."
    

class PersonImage(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

urls.py
app_name = 'galleries'
urlpatterns = [
    # Home page
    path("", views.index, name="index"),

    # Page that shows all persons.
    path('persons/', views.persons, name='persons'),
    # Detail page for a single person.
    path('persons/<int:person_id>/<int:personimage_id>/', views.person_detail, name='person_detail'),
    
    # Page that shows all events.
    path('events', views.events, name='events'),
    # Detail page for a single event.
    path('events/<int:event_id>/', views.event_detail, name='event_detail'),
]

urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

views.py
def index(request):
    """The home page for History Gallery."""
    return render(request, 'galleries/index.html')


def persons(request):
    """Show all persons."""
    persons = Person.objects.all()
    context = {'persons': persons}
    return render(request, 'galleries/persons.html', context)


def person_detail(request, person_id, personimage_id):
    """Show a single person's details."""
    person = Person.objects.get(id=person_id)
    image = PersonImage.objects.get(id=personimage_id)

    person_details = person.persondetail_set.all()
    person_image = image.imagedetail_set.all()
    context = {'person': person, 'person_details': person_details, 'person_image': person_image}
    return render(request, 'galleries/person_detail.html', context)

persons.html
{% extends 'galleries/base.html' %}

{% block content %}
<p>Persons</p>
<ul>
    {% for person in persons %}
        <li>
            <a href="{% url 'galleries:person_detail' person.id personimage.id %}">{{ person.person_text }}</li>
    {% empty %}
        <li>No persons have been added yet.</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endblock content %}

person_detail.html
{% extends 'galleries/base.html' %}

{% block content %}
<p>Person: {{ person.person_text }}</p>

<p>Details:</p>
<ul>
    {% for person_detail in person_details %}
        <li>
            <p>{{ person_detail.person_subtext|linebreaks }}</p>
        </li>
    {% empty %}
        <li>There are no details for this person yet.</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
<ul>
    {% for person_image in person_images %}
        <li>
            <p>{{ person_image.image }}</p>
            <p>{{ person_image.name }}</p>
        </li>
    {% empty %}
        <li>There are no images for this person yet.</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endblock content %}

Error:
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/galleries/persons/

Django Version: 5.0.3
Python Version: 3.12.3
Installed Applications:
['galleries.apps.GalleriesConfig',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']


Template error:
In template C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\python\history_gallery\hg_project\galleries\templates\galleries\persons.html, error at line 8
   Reverse for 'person_detail' with arguments '(5, '')' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['galleries/persons/(?P<person_id>[0-9]+)/(?P<personimage_id>[0-9]+)/\\Z']
   1 : {% extends 'galleries/base.html' %}
   2 : 
   3 : {% block content %}
   4 : <p>Persons</p>
   5 : <ul>
   6 :     {% for person in persons %}
   7 :         <li>
   8 :             <a href=" {% url 'galleries:person_detail' person.id person.personimage_set.first.id %} ">{{ person.person_text }}</li>
   9 :     {% empty %}
   10 :         <li>No persons have been added yet.</li>
   11 :     {% endfor %}
   12 : </ul>
   13 : {% endblock content %}

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\python\history_gallery\hg_project\galleries\views.py", line 17, in persons
    return render(request, 'galleries/persons.html', context)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py", line 25, in render
    content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py", line 62, in render_to_string
    return template.render(context, request)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py", line 61, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 171, in render
    return self._render(context)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 163, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 1000, in render
    return SafeString("".join([node.render_annotated(context) for node in self]))
                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 961, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 159, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 163, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 1000, in render
    return SafeString("".join([node.render_annotated(context) for node in self]))
                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 961, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 65, in render
    result = block.nodelist.render(context)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 1000, in render
    return SafeString("".join([node.render_annotated(context) for node in self]))
                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 961, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py", line 242, in render
    nodelist.append(node.render_annotated(context))
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 961, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py", line 479, in render
    url = reverse(view_name, args=args, kwargs=kwargs, current_app=current_app)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\django\urls\base.py", line 88, in reverse
    return resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 851, in _reverse_with_prefix
    raise NoReverseMatch(msg)
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Exception Type: NoReverseMatch at /galleries/persons/
Exception Value: Reverse for 'person_detail' with arguments '(5, '')' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['galleries/persons/(?P<person_id>[0-9]+)/(?P<personimage_id>[0-9]+)/\\Z']


Don't make us guess what the error is and where it happens.  Post the full error traceback message.

My bad. I added the error to the post.

From where you passing the personimage variable in template context, i can't see any code in your view. just try to debug by adding  {{personimage.id}} - person image id in your template before using it in url whether your getting it or not. As per my understanding this error it because of you are not getting ``{{personimage.id}}and yourperson_detail`  url need the some integer value not empty value.

There is no such value as personimage in Person.

You're passing a variable named person_image to the template, but the template is trying to use a different variable named personimage, which does not exist.

Shown code does not match shown error traceback. In error you have person.personimage_set.first.id whereas in the persons.html template you have personimage.id. And I don't see why would you need to pass image id to every person page.

If your intent was NOT to have many details for each person and many images for each person with no match between details and images (for example, 7 details, 11 images for a single person) then the model design needs adjustments.
